# I added a way for my app to save persistent data but its not saving upon crash

Tags: android, file-io

I have a list view showing Movies, and when you click a movie it adds to Bookmarks. I can view the bookmark from any activity through the action bar. So far it seems to be working, but when I force crash my app through settings the file is no longer existing, I have a feeling I am not saving it correctly. Please advise, here is my relevant code:

Bookmark class that shows a list of bookmarks and has save / load method

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class Bookmarks extends ListActivity {
    private static File directory;
    private static final String FILENAME = "Bookmarks";
    private static ArrayList<Movie> movies = new ArrayList<Movie>();
    private ArrayList<String> tempList;

    public Bookmarks(File file) {
        directory = file;
        Log.e("bookmarkdir", directory + "");
    }

    public Bookmarks() {
        loadBookmark();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Log.e("BOOKMAKRCREAT", "");
        loadBookmark();
        if (movies != null) {
            Log.e("null", "a");
            setListAdapter(new MovieAdapter(this, R.layout.viewmovie, movies,
                    (int) Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory()));
        } else {
            Log.e("notnull", "a");
            tempList = new ArrayList<String>();
            tempList.add("NO BOOKMARKS FOUND");
            setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, tempList));
        }

    }



    public void addBookmark(Movie movie) {
        try {
            if (!movies.contains(movie)) {
                movies.add(movie);
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(new File(directory,
                        FILENAME));
                ObjectOutputStream os = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
                os.writeObject(movies);
                Log.e("saving bookmarks", movies.toString());
                os.flush();
                os.close();
            } else {
                Log.e("dupe", "not adding dupe movie");
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            Log.e("FileNotFound from Bookmarks", e + "");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("IOException from Bookmarks", e + "");
        }
    }

    public void loadBookmark() {
        try {
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(new File(directory,
                    FILENAME));
            ObjectInputStream is = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
            movies = (ArrayList<Movie>) is.readObject();
            Log.e("loading bookmarks", movies.toString());
            is.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            Log.e("FileNotFound from Bookmarks", e + "");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("IOException from Bookmarks", e + "");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            Log.e("ClassNotFound from Bookmarks", e + "");
        }

    }

}
```

Because this activity isn't exactly created on start up I have to send it the getFileDirs() from the calling class which is ViewMovies. I was a bit confused on doing the file directory part, I have done saving many times but not on android and am not sure exactly how it works. I know that when I print getFilesDirs it is `/data/data/com.example.moviesearch/`files. I accessed the folder and saw the Bookmark file inside the said path through the file explorer of eclipse.

here is my calling class where you click add bookmark

```
public class ViewMovies extends ListActivity implements OnItemClickListener {
    ArrayList<Movie> movies;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        int maxMemory = (int) (Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory() / 1024);
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        ArrayList<Movie> movielist = extras.getParcelableArrayList("movielist");
        movies = movielist;

        MovieAdapter adapter = new MovieAdapter(this, R.layout.viewmovie,
                movielist, maxMemory);
        setListAdapter(adapter);
        ListView lv = getListView();
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
        new Bookmarks(getFilesDir()).addBookmark(movies.get(arg2));
        Toast.makeText(arg0.getContext(), "Added bookmark", 6).show();

    }

}
```

Comment: So lemme get this straight. You are saving objects of type `Movie` and then when you load them, you are putting them in an ArrayList to use in your listview?

Comment: I am saving an array list of movies and yes putting them into a custom array listview. Every time I force crash the file is removed, but prior to the crash the file is visible. I read it maybe because I used the keyword static but I removed it and still lose data

Comment: Hi there. I posted an answer, I'm not sure if it would work in your project but it's worked for me so yeah :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this class to serialize and deserialize your movie objects..

```
public class ObjectSerializer {

    public static String serialize(Serializable obj) throws IOException {
        if (obj == null) return "";
        try {
            ByteArrayOutputStream serialObj = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            ObjectOutputStream objStream = new ObjectOutputStream(serialObj);
            objStream.writeObject(obj);
            objStream.close();
            return encodeBytes(serialObj.toByteArray());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw WrappedIOException.wrap("Serialization error: " + e.getMessage(), e);
        }
    }

    public static Object deserialize(String str) throws IOException {
        if (str == null || str.length() == 0) return null;
        try {
            ByteArrayInputStream serialObj = new ByteArrayInputStream(decodeBytes(str));
            ObjectInputStream objStream = new ObjectInputStream(serialObj);
            return objStream.readObject();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw WrappedIOException.wrap("Deserialization error: " + e.getMessage(), e);
        }
    }

    public static String encodeBytes(byte[] bytes) {
        StringBuffer strBuf = new StringBuffer();

        for (int i = 0; i < bytes.length; i++) {
            strBuf.append((char) (((bytes[i] >> 4) & 0xF) + ((int) 'a')));
            strBuf.append((char) (((bytes[i]) & 0xF) + ((int) 'a')));
        }

        return strBuf.toString();
    }

    public static byte[] decodeBytes(String str) {
        byte[] bytes = new byte[str.length() / 2];
        for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i+=2) {
            char c = str.charAt(i);
            bytes[i/2] = (byte) ((c - 'a') << 4);
            c = str.charAt(i+1);
            bytes[i/2] += (c - 'a');
        }
        return bytes;
    }

}
```

Here is how I would save the bookmark...

```
public void addBookmark(Movie movie) {
        Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>();
        List<String> strings = new ArrayList<String>();
        try {
            if (!movies.contains(movie)) {
                movies.add(movie);
                // serialize all the movies in your arraylist
                for (Movie m : movies) {
                    strings.add(ObjectSerializer.serialize(m));
                }
                //add the serialized movies to a set so it can be put in
                // shared preferences
                set.addAll(strings);
                // add the set to shared preferences to ve saved
                SharedPreferences prefs = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(
                        "Saved Bookmarks", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                SharedPreferences.Editor prefsEditor = prefs.edit();
                prefsEditor.putStringSet("aName", set);
                prefsEditor.commit();
                Log.e("saving bookmarks", movies.toString());
            } else {
                Log.e("dupe", "not adding dupe movie");
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            Log.e("FileNotFound from Bookmarks", e + "");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("IOException from Bookmarks", e + "");
        }
    }
```

Now to get the data back, here is how you would implement loadBookmark...

```
public void loadBookmark() {
        Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>();
        SharedPreferences prefs = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(
                  "Saved Bookarks", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        set = prefs.getStringSet("aName", null);
        movies.clear();
        for (String s : set) {
            movies.add((Movie)ObjectSerializer.deserialize(s));
        }
        Log.e("loading bookmarks", movies.toString());
    }
```

Comment: before I even attempt this because it is changing a lot of my code can you explain the purpose of the serialize class and what you are doing differently? the main thing I notice is you are using shared pref instead of storing it to disk, is the way I do it not preventing data from being lost? also thanks, I will try to see if anything improves

Comment: @CatznDogz Yeah the main thing that is changing is the fact that im storing the bookmarks in shared preferences. Also, because your code is nicely encapsulated, you dont have to change much, simple add the Serializer Class into your project, and just commet out your load and save bookmark methods and paste mine in. If it doesnt work you can just delete my two methods and uncomment your methods.

Comment: OK thanks, the main reason I asked was because it looks kind of complicating the code you use,  It is not something I would come up with myself lol. I have heard of other ways to store shared pref such as converting my object to json, but I really wanted to get it working using file i/o to disk with serialization. If I can't get it working I guess ill have to just switch to shared preferences, either way ill be back with updates!

Comment: @CatznDogz Basically the serialize class turns your movie objects into a stream of bytes, these bytes can be added to a string set so they can be put in shared preferences. They must be serialized first because shared preferences cant store non-primitive data. Also note, if your movie class has any non-serializable variables such as `bitmap` or something, use the keyword `transient` when you declare them, it stops them from being serialized

Comment: @CatznDogz Okay, all the best. :)

Comment: Turns out I was not loading the right file this whole time...><

Comment: @CatznDogz Haha, I guess we'll never know if my answer would have actually worked or not. xD

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
os.flush();
os.close();
```

Try:

```
fos.flush();
fos.close();
```

Its the Filestream you want to dispose

Comment: This didn't seem to change any behavior. I thought closing os will also close fos because os wraps fos?

Comment: Your right, apparently only os.close() should be used.
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.html

os.flush() does nothing, see:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/io/OutputStream.html#flush%28%29

Have you tried using just os.close()?

Answer (score 0):

okay to handle force close ..

You need to close both FileOutputStreams not just one..that is why you still see the behavior when you do a force close..thus put a FileOutputStream close in your loadBookmark block

Make Sense?